# how to code this animated string in bash better and simpler?

Tags: bash

```
clear
echo "loading"
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "Loading"
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "lOading"
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "loAding"
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "loaDing"
sleep 0.6  
clear
echo "loadIng"
sleep 0.6  
clear
echo "loadiNg"
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "loadinG"
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "loading."
sleep 0.6
clear  
echo "loading.."
sleep 0.6
clear  
echo "loading..."
sleep 0.6
clear
echo "loading"
sleep 0.6
clear
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Do really want to clear the screen every time? Read `man clear`. Could you use `/bin/echo -n "\rString2   "`? Read `man echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid hardcoding the different letter case combinations, and remove a lot of duplication in the process, by using the shell's *parameter expansion* features to slice the string and upper-case one character in turn.

As well, you could use `printf` to insert carriage returns in place of `echo`'s default newlines - that way, you can avoid having to call `clear` at every step.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

str='loading'
dly=0.6

printf '%s\r' "$str"
sleep "$dly"

for ((i=0;i<${#str};i++)); do
  l=${str:0:i}; r=${str:i}
  printf '%s%s\r' "${l}" "${r^}"
  sleep "$dly"
done

for ellipsis in . .. ... "    "; do
  printf '%s%s\r' "${str}" "${ellipsis}"
  sleep "$dly"
done
```

Comment: ok i will give it a try according to what you suggest

Comment: thank you so much steeldriver, this is what im looking for,,,,